# Is it too late to program an app in swift 2.3?

Tags: ios, swift

When apple releases iOS 10 officially will we have to start programming with swift 3 or will it be still possible to release apps in swift 2.3?

Comment: Too late?  No, actually it's too early.  Swift 2.3 is only available in Xcode 8 which is still in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In addition to Swift 3, Xcode 8 supports development with Swift 2.3, a minor update to the Swift 2.2 language built to work with the new SDKs for macOS Sierra, iOS 10, tvOS 10, and watchOS 3.](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=36) .

So yes, you can use Swift 2.3 for iOS 10.

Comment: Apple has also confirmed they will accept binaries written in Swift 2.3 to the App Store when Xcode 8 officially releases.